# Gradle: 'buildTypes' cannot be applied to groovy.lang.Closure

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After changing `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` to 22, and changing my `buildToolsVersion` to 22.0.1, I keep getting the following error:

> 'buildTypes' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure<
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType>)'

I looked at my `build.gradle` file and tried to look for anything that could be an error:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "********"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 17
        versionName "1.5-beta"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        freeFlavour {
            applicationId "********"
        }
        paidFlavour {
            applicationId "********"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Cleaning the project helped for me.

Comment: Interesting.... I wonder why the error appears in the first place.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Answer:

For some reason, I found that cutting (`Ctrl + X`) the `buildTypes` section and pasting it below the `productFlavours` section, then moving it back to where it was seemed to solve the issue.

Comment: Damn you are right! It's unbelievable how many bugs google has in all of its products. Actually they are trying to make a developer's experience a living hell -.-

Comment: Annoyingly enough, this is contrast to what `Gradle` has on their [website](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Running-ProGuard).

Comment: For what it's worth, I also undid the changes, and it seemed to still work so I don't know just what this does.

Comment: Haha SH** Google.. you are right I did CTR+X then CTRL+V solved my problem!

Comment: a simple solution for this issue - Just invalidate caches and restart from -----> Android studio - File -  Invalidate caches and restart